# Python - Flask API request body validation using marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

I do validation for request body in Flask API using the following code below:

```
# This function validates the request body
def validatefilterdata(data):
    class FilterDataSchema(Schema):
        masterBotId = fields.Str(validate=validate.Length(min=1), 
        required=False)
        useCaseId = fields.Str(validate=validate.Length(min=1), required=False)
        month = fields.Str(required=False)
        dateRange = fields.Dict(required=False)

   filetdata_schema = FilterDataSchema(strict=True)
   validation_result = filetdata_schema.load(data)
   return validation_result.errors
```

My requirement is this:
**Allow dictionary as well as String values for 'useCaseId' field(Currently 'useCaseId' field will accept only dictionary values according to the validation code above**

Comment: Looks like it will only accept strings, not dicts.

Comment: BTW, not an answer to your question, but you could consider using webargs to deserialize flask request body with marshmallow.